# Using FileOpenPicker with Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Windows Phone 8.1 supports file open and file save pickers. I want to use a file open picker with a project which was converted form WP 8 to WP 8.1 (Silverlight).

I can open the FileOpenPicker as follows:

```
FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
picker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

Now, all examples I have found use the new universal Windows runtime where the resulting files are catched as follows in the App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e) {     
    ContinuationActivatedEventArgs = e as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs; 
    if (ContinuationEventArgsChanged != null) 
    { 
        // Handle file here
    } 
}
```

The problem is that the converted Silverlight apps do not implement this method. Instead I derived the principle idea from another example for Silverlight apps (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn655125%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    var eventArgs = e as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
    if (eventArgs != null)
    {
        // Handle file here
    }
}
```

But this does not work (e.g. `eventArgs` is always `NULL`).

There is another example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642086%28v=vs.105%29.aspx. This uses the following method in the app.xaml.cs:

```
private void Application_ContractActivated(object sender, IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
        var filePickerContinuationArgs = e as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;
        if (filePickerContinuationArgs != null)
        {
        // Handle file here
        }
}
```

But this method is never called in my app.

Has someone a hint/idea how get the FileOpenPicker to work with a Silverlight WP8.1 app?

Regards,

Comment: Which values does e contain? Have you tried all the other lifetime events of App and PhoneApplicationService? Have you tried await picker.PickSingleFileAsync()

Comment: Update to your update: You could try to manually add the event handler to Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ContractActivated.

Comment: Thanks! Manually adding the event handler works. Can you post your answer as an answer so that I can mark it?

Comment: Great that it works. Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that one needs to manually add an event handler to Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ContractActivated:

```
Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ContractActivated +=  Application_ContractActivated;

private void Application_ContractActivated(object sender, IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
        var filePickerContinuationArgs = e as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;
        if (filePickerContinuationArgs != null)
        {
        // Handle file here
        }
}
```

Comment: Where should I need to this event, in App.Xaml.cs?

Comment: Yes. Put the ContractActivated += ... code in the constructor of App.xaml.cs and the event handler somewhere in the same class.